# Creating a percent with amcharts

Tags: javascript, ajax, amcharts

I have some data that gets graphed using amCharts.  I get all the data then post it when the user generates a graph.  function loadChart(data) {

```
var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
chart.dataProvider = data;
chart.categoryField = "age";
catAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
catAxis.gridCount = data.length;
chart.pathToImages = "../images/";
var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph.balloonText = "[[category]]: [[value]]";
graph.valueField = "probability"
graph.type = "smoothedLine";
graph.numberFormatter = {precision:2, decimalSeparator:'.', thousandsSeparator:','};
graph.lineAlpha = 1;
chart.addGraph(graph);
```

Is there anyway to take the data which is a decimal and multiply it by 100 to get the percent using amCharts or do I have to change the data that is being sent to amCharts to create the graph.

Answer (score 2):

```
graph.balloonText = "$[[category]]([[percents]]%)";
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Are you assuming that `percents` is another data field passed in that's already been multiplied by 100?

Comment: This works actually. In newer version of amCharts 3.x the syntax is: `"balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[percents]]"`